# Push the second flex item with a fixed min width to next line and make the first flex item fill the remaining width

Tags: css

I'm having issue with a CSS flex layout. I have an array of fields which I wanted to display like in the image below. Basically I have fixed width of input element (`325px`) and I want the width to expand and fill the remaining spaces when the first flex element is long enough to be wrapped into next line.

[image]

I wrote the code below and can achieve the behavior I wanted but there is an issue where the input width cannot stay fixed (`325px`) when the text is short. Can anyone point me in the right direction or if you have any alternative solution? Thanks in advance!

```css
.container {
  width: 450px;
}

.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   gap: 5px 10px;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
}

.field {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="field">Short field</div>
    <input class="input"/>
  </div>
  
  <br/>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="field">This is a very very very very very long field</div>
    <input class="input"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to make all the flex children to grow with automatic sizing using `flow-basis: auto`. The code below did the trick:

```
.wrapper > * {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}


input {
  min-width: 350px
}
```

Thanks to [MDN Docs - Mastering Wrapping of Flex Items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items#collapsed_items) for pointing me into the right direction :)